# Delayed Snare sound

Tags: sound-design, replication, samples, sample

Hey guys Im trying to get this sort of delayed snare sound,  I think it may be my sample that IM using but kinda wanted to see how this is made.  It seems like a snare drum that is delayed at very short miliseconds, somewhere between 75-90,   Im using fab filters timeless to get the sort of effect you here in this track.  You will hear this sort of snare that is repeated really fast.  It occurs at 1:10 and 1:26 of the track below

Any thoughts of how to get this effect would be greatly appreciated.  I tried messing with the delay somewhat but cant seem to find it sounding similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a short snare ruff sample, not delay. Listen to this guy 2/3 in here:

Comment: yes Ive actually figured that out in the meantime.  Its like a 16th note followed by a 32nd note,  if you put some minor delay on that like I described in my original question, it sounds pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a delay, or an effect.  It is called a roll.  16th notes, 32 notes, and even 64th notes can create this effect.

It's important to know that a crescendo (a gradual increase in volume), or a decrescendo (gradual decrease in volume) will enhance the effect.

I made a clip that you can easily reproduce. [Snare roll sound](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-WufHYpa6LHdGlaYVVLMHZFc0k/view?usp=sharing)
It is a roll using 32nd notes beginning with a very quiet note gradually increasing until the last couple of notes that are loud.

Best,

E. Love
Please like my fb page!  http://www.facebook.com/PureHeatEnt